# Select para criar saldo com base no valor do mês anterior

Tags: php, mysql, select

Estou com a seguinte situação. Tenho uma base Mysql onde uma das colunas (liquido_dia) traz o valor diário gerado (positivo ou negativo), já estou montando nela um demonstrativo por mês do valor gerado no mês usando o GROUP BY MONTH(data).

O que estou precisando agora é gerar uma nova coluna (imagem abaixo) com saldo acumulado, pegando sempre o valor do mês anterior e somando ao novo mês. Estou programando em PHP com o banco em Mysql

SQL que já estou fazendo

```
SELECT * FROM operacoes WHERE id_usuario = '{$codigoUser}' GROUP BY MONTH(data)
```

Tela que já estou trazendo alguns dados, mais notem que a coluna ACUMUALDO esta vindo a suma errada, é o que estou tentado corrigir no select[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto será usado para verificar se o usuário esta com saldo positivo ou negativo no mês e saber se ele deve gerar DARF de imposto ou fazer compensação do negativo para os próximos meses.

Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

obrigado por sua resposta.
Rodei sua consulta no meu banco para testar, veja como ele retornou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Somente ajustes para os nomes das minhas colunas e deu um GORUP BY para trazer a soma de cada mês

```
set @csum := 0;
select data, liquido_dia, (@csum := @csum + liquido_dia) as acumulado from operacoes GROUP BY month(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar uma variável Mysql

Exemplo no SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ed061/4

```
CREATE TABLE `operacoes` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mes` date NOT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `operacoes` (`id`, `mes`, `valor`) VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01', '670.04'),
(2, '2020-02-01', '453.00'),
(3, '2020-03-01', '154.00'),
(4, '2020-04-01', '543.00')

set @csum := 0;
select mes, valor, (@csum := @csum + valor) as acumulado
from operacoes
order by mes;
```

Isso calcula a soma parcial de forma corrente